# My Android APK show google map On sony phone but don''t show on huawei phones

Tags: android, google-maps, google-api, google-play-services, google-maps-android-api-2

I have a problem for showing google map on android apk.

I develop this on google API 2.1 and it's work on sony experia z but not work on huawei phone or lower sony phone...

on my phone( sony experia z) that's work exactly...

I user : google api2.1 , 
         (google_play_services_lib versionCode:3027110, versionName="3.0.27 (601249-10)")

Edited :

android manifest Code:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="BamSystem.UrbanMarkets.Activity"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />


    <permission android:name="android.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>
    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />

    <application


        <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
                android:value="6" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="API_KEY"/>

    </application>
```

google map activity :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#FFFFFF"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#f05a00"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:height="48dp"
    android:text="title"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="30dp" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/lnrMap"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:visibility="visible" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you have Google Play Services app installed on your device.

Comment: hi David, I test my app on tablet( lenovo) google play services is 4 but map not work, (I added my manifest and layout to question)

Comment: can u post the logcat  content here when you open the map fragment at run time ?

Answer (score 0):

On May 16, 2019, the US government placed Huawei on its Entity List. This government action prohibits all US companies, including Google, from collaborating with Huawei.

This means that Google is prohibited from working with Huawei on new device models or providing Google’s apps including Gmail, Maps, YouTube, the Play Store and others for preload or download on these devices.

more info here
https://support.google.com/android/thread/29434011?hl=en